# Desire2Learn Valence API - Is is possible to get the content for a document?

Tags: desire2learn

We are using the Valence API to get the content for a course.
We can use the modules API to get the topics in a module

e.g.

```
{
    "TopicType": 1,
    "Url": "/content/enforced/6671-Sandbox_101/Document 1.html",
    "StartDate": null,
    "EndDate": null,
    "IsHidden": false,
    "IsLocked": false,
    "Id": 560,
    "Title": "Document 1",
    "ShortTitle": "",
    "Type": 1
}
```

The Url that defines the content for the document is:
/content/enforced/6671-Sandbox_101/Document 1.html

If I access that in a browser as an authenticated user I can get the data.
However, we want to be able to access the data using a backend process which is authenticating using the Valence API auth scheme.

I can find references in the Valence docs for uploading files, for downloading files from the learning object repository, but I can't find any references for how we could download course files.

Anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of v10.2.0 of the D2L Learning Suite in May of 2013, an API exists to let callers [fetch back the underlying data](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#get--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-content-topics-(topicId)-file) for a file-type content topic. In order to use this API, the back-end service needs to offer the LE product component at v10.2.0 or later, and offer the v1.3 or later LE API contract.